# Maya: Python Script does not execute if the first letter is not Capitalized?

Tags: python, maya

I created identical Python scripts for maya and saved as 2 versions in the scripts folder:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def function(selection=False):
# some code here

# create a window with a botton. 
window =  cmds.window(w= 300, h=100)
loadBtn=cmds.button(w=50, h=25, label="Click Me", c= "function()")    
cmds.showWindow(window)
```

Version 1: myScript.py

Version 2: MyScript.py

The only difference above is the first Letter, and I excuted the following command in the Python Script Editor in Maya:

```
import myScript
reload(myScript)
```

Result: no window pops up, But change myScript to MyScript:

```
import MyScript
reload(MyScript)
```

a window pops up.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Python module names are case sensitive under the hood: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0235/

It's bad practice to have two copies of the same file which differ only in casing, because if you tried to port your scripts over to a windows install (for examples) you'd end up with one, randomly selected file instead.